# UIWebView not loading

Tags: xcode, ios5, uiwebview, tableview

I know this is such a simple problem, but I have been struggling with it and it just will not work.  I am trying to get a UITableView to open a URL when a specific row is selected.  Using NSLog I am able to see that the urlSelected variable is being set correctly and being passed to the UrlViewController properly, but it simply isn't displaying the webview.  It is only displaying a navigation menu with a black screen.  If I add a push relationship between the two view controllers, then the ViewController loads correctly but it has trouble passing the urlSelected variable to the UrlViewController.  What is the proper way to pass this variable, or do I need to set up a different relationship between the two ViewControllers?  Here is what I have currently:

RootViewController.m:

```
    #import "RootViewController.h"
    #import "UrlViewController.h"
    ..........
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath         *)indexPath
    {

        UrlViewController *webController = [[UrlViewController alloc] init];


        if(indexPath.row == 0){
            webController.urlAddress = @"http://www.yahoo.com";
            NSLog(@"urlAddress being passed is:%@", webController.urlAddress);
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:webController animated:YES];

        }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
            webController.urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
            NSLog(@"urlAddress being passed is:%@", webController.urlAddress);
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:webController animated:YES];


        }else{
            webController.urlAddress = @"http://www.abc.com";
            NSLog(@"urlAddress being passed is:%@", webController.urlAddress);
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:webController animated:YES];

        }    

    }
```

UrlViewController.h:

```
      @interface UrlViewController : UIViewController{
          NSString *urlAddress;
      }
      @property (strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
      @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *urlAddress;
```

UrlViewController.m:

```
      @implementation UrlViewController
      @synthesize webView;
      @synthesize urlAddress;
      ...........
     - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];
        NSLog(@"The value being receieved is:%@", urlAddress);
    }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

I receive the following output from the NSLogs:

```
    2012-03-28 09:53:30.266 BeloitTurner[4278:f803] urlAddress being passed is:http://www.yahoo.com
    2012-03-28 09:53:30.269 BeloitTurner[4278:f803] The value being receieved is:http://www.yahoo.com
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I've answered this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791517/pass-a-uiwebview-request-using-prepareforsegue/13723765#13723765)! It's quiet the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using a storyboard that contains the views for both RootViewController and UrlViewController. If that's the case, you need to instantiate your UrlViewController using the storyboard:

```
UrlViewController* webController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"UrlViewController"];
```

Use this instead of how you alloc init the webController in your tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method. Also, in the storyboard containing the views for both of these view controllers, set the Identifier field under the View Controller section of the Attributes inspector in Interface Builder to be the string UrlViewController. The reason for doing it this way instead of just alloc init is that the file describing the view for the UrlViewController is inside the storyboard, so alloc initing the UrlViewController means it won't find its associated view and just show you a black screen.

You could also do this with the Push relationship. Instead of the tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, you would simply set up the Push relationship (a segue) from the cell in the RootViewController to the UrlViewController. In your RootViewController.m file, add the following method:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"PassUrlToUrlViewControllerSegue"]) {
        segue.destinationViewController.urlAddress = @"http://www.yahoo.com";
    }
}
```

This would require you to set the Identifier for the Push segue to work. Select the arrow representing the Push segue in the storyboard and set its Identifier to the string PassUrlToUrlViewControllerSegue.

You could make this dynamic by using the sender parameter given to you in prepareForSegue:sender: to identify which cell was selected and thus which url to pass along.