# Passing uiwebview request using prepareforsegue in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I am new to IOS, I am trying to create an app where I need to display the webview of any site along with slide out menus . To achieve this I have tried using swrevealviewcontroller to get the slide out menu working and use the uiwebview on the controller page  but now I need to pass url to webview from the slide out menu working with single uiwebview.

How can I achieve this , I have tried using this link 
[Pass a UIWebView request using prepareForSegue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8791517/pass-a-uiwebview-request-using-prepareforsegue)

but I am stuck at one point , I am getting error as 
Urlstr does not belong to the class , I have checked it

it will be great if anyone could guide me with the complete step

Answer (score 1):

Add an NSString property to the ViewController you are presenting like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *webviewURLString;
```

Then when you present assign the ViewController's `webviewURLString` property with something like this:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
// THIS IS WHERE YOU ASSIGN IT
myVC.webviewURLString = @"<your url goes here>";
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

Then when in MyViewController's `viewDidLoad` method you can check if `webviewURLString` has a value and if it does, start loading the web view with the url from `webviewURLString`.